# What's the difference between avd from command line and from avd manager?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, appium

I am trying run appium test case on android emulator,but there is a confusing situation.

The test case will start a specified activity, is very fast on the android emulator from **avd manager**(5-6s).

avd manager:

[avd manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIdrQ.jpg)

The android emulator from **command line** is also relatively smooth，but the test case start the specified activity very slow(20-30s).It can fast infrequently(1%-2%).

command line:

```
emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_27
```

The avd is same.So,is there any difference between the same avd from command line and from avd manager ?

I've tried a lot of acceleration options but they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

When you open emulator from avd then it opens using commandline itself but with some startup options. Following command is executed when you run emulator from avd

emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_21 -netdelay none -netspeed full

Try to include these options in your command line instead of normal run. You can run your command like this:

emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_27 -netdelay none -netspeed full

i hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it, but it didn't work.
[In the android developers docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline), `-netdelay none -netspeed full` are default options.